# Delphi, INDY, cant connect TLSv1.2 (wireshark says its okay? oO)

Tags: tls1.2, indy10

Indy 10.6.2, trying to 'GET' https://dapi.binance.com/dapi/v1/time

The handshake fails with 'Alert protocol version'

That's weird, because the server should support TLSv1.2, and according to Wireshark, my program does everything in TLSv1.2

I tried doing the same query with my browser (successfully). The 'Server hello' packet contained a Cypher that my program offers (so I think the problem is not my CipherList)

CLIENT HELLO
[image]
ALERT: HANDSHAKE FAILURE
[image]
ALERT: PROTOCOL VERSION
[image]

At this point I don't quite understand what is the actual problem. Why does the handshake fail, why doesn't server like my 'protocol version' while uses it itself? o_O

Comment: Your app’s TLS 1.2 handshake hello does not include the SNI extension, which most modern TLS 1.2 servers require.  Make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy, which does use SNI on outgoing handshakes (since Jan 2016)

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, indeed. I've reinstalled Indy today, did everything the same, now my Client_Hello packet contains this extension and everything works fine, thanks a lot! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll check it as the right one <3